# sgml to xml conversion

Tags: xslt, c#-2.0, sgml

I have a following sample sgml data from my .sgm file and I want convert this in to xml

```
<?dtd name="viewed">
<?XMLDOC>
<viewed >xyz
<cite>
<yr>2010
<pno cite="2010 abc 1188">10
<?/XMLDOC>

<?XMLDOC>
<viewed>abc.
<cite>
<yr>2010
<pno cite="2010 xyz 5133">9
<?/XMLDOC>
```

Output should be like this:

```
<index1>
    <num viewed="xyz"/>
    <heading>xyz</heading>
    <index-refs>
      <link  caseno="2010 abc 1188</link>
    </index-refs>
  </index-1>
<index1>
    <num viewed="abc"/>
    <heading>abc</heading>
    <index-refs>
      <link  caseno="2010 xyz 5133</link>
    </index-refs>
  </index-1>
```

Can this be done in c# or can we use xslt 2.0 to do this kind of conversion?

Comment: You need an SGML parser to do this properly. XSLT 2.0 doesn't provide such a parser; you could theoretically write one in XSLT 2.0 but it would be a huge pain. I don't know what support there is for parsing SGML in C#.

Answer (score 6):

Others have already given some good advice. Here's one way of putting it all together by first converting the input SGML to well-formed XML and then using XSLT to transform that to the exact format you need.

**Converting your SGML to well-formed XML**

The `osx` tool from the [OpenSP](http://openjade.sourceforge.net/) package [suggested by mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452537/sgml-to-xml-convertion/4454475#4454475) is a good tool for this. Since your SGML markup omits end tags, you need to have a DTD from which the correct nesting of elements can be determined. If you don't have a DTD, you need to create one. For your example input, it could be as simple as this:

```
<!ELEMENT toplevel o o (viewed)+>

<!ELEMENT viewed - o (#PCDATA,cite)>
<!ELEMENT cite - o (yr,pno)>
<!ELEMENT yr - o (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pno - o (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST pno cite CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

You also need to add a proper doctype declaration to the beginning of your SGML file. Assuming you have your DTD in file `viewed.dtd`.

```
<!DOCTYPE toplevel SYSTEM "viewed.dtd" >
```

With this addition, you should now be able use `osx` to convert the SGML to XML. (It won't be able to convert the processing instructions which start with a `/` as those are not allowed in XML, and will emit a warning about them.)

```
osx input.sgm > input.xml
```

**Transforming the resulting XML to your desired format**

For the above case, you could use something like the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="VIEWED">
    <index1>
      <num viewed="{normalize-space(text())}"/>
      <heading>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(text())"/>
      </heading>
      <index-refs>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CITE"/>
      </index-refs>
    </index1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CITE">
    <link caseno="{PNO/@CITE}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, Jukka Matilainen, "osx input.sgm > input.xml" Could you please provide Link to download that "OSX" EXE and supporting files...

Comment: @Thirusanguraja Venkatesan, you can find download links from the sourceforge downloads page for the openjade/opensp project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openjade/files/opensp/1.5.2/

Comment: **osx.exe** not available in **OpenSP-1.5.2-win32.zip**, but I am followed the instruction given in http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/build.htm , Finally i got EXE files, Thanks for Good Guidance..

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the **osx** SGML to XML converter. It is part of the OpenSP package (based on SP, originally written by James Clark).

- http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/index.htm
- http://www.jclark.com/sp/index.htm

Comment: I routinely use osx for SGML to XML conversion, it works very well.

Answer (score -1):

Can the **[SGML-Reader](http://dekiwiki.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dekiwiki/public/sgmlreader/1.8.7/)**, originally developed by Chris Lovett help in solving this problem?

Comment: There are various code examples available. See: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PostprocessingAutoClosedSGMLTagsWithTheSGMLReader.aspx

Answer (score -1):

**Why XSLT?** I doubt you can map SGML to XML Infoset or XDM...

I think that you should better use the language made for this task: **DSSSL (Document Style Semantics and Specification Language)**

This is the predecessor of XSLT. The author is James Clark. And this is the his [site](http://www.jclark.com/dsssl/).