# Where I can get OpenJade osx and How to convert SGML to XML?

Tags: xml, sgml

Here am trying to convert SGML to XML using OpenSP, http://openjade.sourceforge.net/ using those link I got source file and instruction but I am unable to build Win EXE, So please provide me OSX EXE if available.

Note:
Already I visited Links:

http://openjade.sourceforge.net/

[sgml to xml convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452537/sgml-to-xml-convertion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows binaries for OpenSP 1.5.2 are available from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openjade/files/opensp/1.5.2/.

Included in OpenSP-1.5.2-win32.zip is **osx.exe**, which is the SGML to XML converter you are looking for.

Documentation can be found here: http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/index.htm.

Comment: **osx.exe** not available in **OpenSP-1.5.2-win32.zip**, but I am followed the instruction given in http://openjade.sourceforge.net/doc/build.htm , Finally i got EXE files.

Comment: What are you talking about? osx.exe is indeed included in OpenSP-1.5.2-win32.zip.

Comment: Yeah surely **Bin** folder not available in that Zip, better you can check it. After the completion process in **“build-win32.bat”** only I got the EXE files in BIN folder.